# Photoshop: How do I run / call a JSX script from another JSX script in Photoshop?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, jsx

I have variables and strings in one JSX script that I would like to use in another JSX script in Photoshop.

I wanted to just re-run the first script in the second, and get the variables in there that way. How do I do this?

More details: I am using the first script and am manipulating numbers in that script. When I have finalized my work, I would like for another script to take those numbers and perform some calculations on those variables and prompt me with them so I can copy paste it where I am using it elsewhere.

This is my first post at Stack, I have found tons of information on this site already, it's really great, thanks to everyone here :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695444/adobe-indesign-jsx-script-execute-jsx-script but my answer was longer than the one here.

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution with some more googling. Answer here: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/555016

And this is what it looks like for me. Since I only need to run one script I have the other stuff commented out.

```
var SCRIPTS_FOLDER =  decodeURI(app.path + '/' + localize("$$$/ScriptingSupport/InstalledScripts=Presets/Scripts"));
var geo_dynamic = File(SCRIPTS_FOLDER + "/geo_dynamic.jsx");
//var Script2 = File(SCRIPTS_FOLDER + "/Script2.jsx");
//var Script3 = File(SCRIPTS_FOLDER + "/Script3.jsx");
$.evalFile (geo_dynamic);
//$.evalFile (Script2);
//$.evalFile (Script3);
```

This is a bit over my head but it works. It's interesting it is this complicated to do something so simple! In my beginning perl scripts I have found this to much much easier in perl.

Comment: Here's how it works: the first line creates a string which is the absolute path to the scripts folder, the second loads the 'geo_dynamic' file from that path and the third evaluates the file (runs it inside the current scope).  It's a common pattern in languages which do not have an inherent include or require method.  Scripting languages don't often have convenient support for multiple source file loading, so solutions like this are quite popular, especially as javascript is now often used for wider and more complex applications.  Also welcome!

Comment: Nice! much shorter than what was using (and posted on the other question).

Answer (score 1):

I have just found a better solution to import another jsx.
It´s really simple, just put this line and that´s all:

```
#include "path/to/file.jsx"
```

After that you can use any method of the imported jsx.

An example:

```
#include "path/to/file.jsx"
foreign_method();
```